# Word 2007 textbox management

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, documentation

I am updating a user manual that was initially written by somebody else. 
I know that most manuals are not written in Word, but our office only uses Microsoft Office applications.

I am doing fairly well, creating and applying "styles". 
A lot of the directions in this manual require updated screenshots of the program it documents. 
… It's a big mess. `</rant>`

One thing I am attempting to do is add “call outs” or **Note** text boxes like those seen in modern software manuals. 
I am attempting to do this with the *Text box* feature. 
However, I am having a hard time making them uniform in size and positioning.

Does Word offer a way to manage the size and other properties of textboxes, similar to the way it allows you to manage text in styles? 
I feel that this could (or should) be possible.

Is it possible to manage Text Boxes the same way you can manage styles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called Text Box styles which can be seen up the top menu under "Format" when you  click on a textbox.

To create a new style to save and use later:

1. Select the already formatted textbox.
2. Click on the "Insert" toolbar menu.
3. Click Textbox dropdown
4. Choose save selection to textbox gallery.
5. Fill out the details and click okay.

You can even set this style as the default formatting to apply to new text boxes right clicking on the outside border of the textbox and choosing "Set Autoshape defaults".

Lastly, the above only applies to styles. If size and position is your problem the easiest way to keep that all the same is to use copy and paste :)